# Chrome-extension / Execute different content scripts depending on selection in popup.html

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I need to do an extension with the following behavior. The popup.html should have two buttons or two radio buttons (button is easier because I don't have to save the selected value like with radio) and depending on the user selection I have to execute one script or another. Also after either of the scripts is loaded and the user wants to use the other one, I have to reload the page in order to "unload" the previous one. Could anyone give me an approach to accomplish this?

At the moment I have this:

**popup.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var firstTime = true;
    $("input[name='method']").change(function() {
       if($(this).val() === "events") {
            if(!firstTime) {
                chrome.tabs.reload(null, null, function(){
                    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "content_events.js", runAt: "document_end"});
                });
            } else {
                chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "content_events.js", runAt: "document_end"});
                firstTime = false;
            }
        } else {
            if(!firstTime) {
                chrome.tabs.reload(null, null, function(){
                    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "content_timer.js", runAt: "document_end"});
                });
            } else {
                chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "content_timer.js", runAt: "document_end"});
                firstTime = false;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

**manifest.json**

```
"permissions": [
"tabs",
"activeTab",
"<all_urls>"
],
```

The first time the script is loaded properly, but when I change it the page reloads but the new script is not loaded (I think it's loaded before the page refresh). I tried with all the possibilities for the runAt attribute and also without it. I tried without injecting the script in the callback function of the tabs.reload too with no luck.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to inject a Javascript file into a page depending on the value of a variable. You could set a listener with the **chrome.tabs.onUpdated** method and then call **chrome.tabs.executeScript** to inject the correct file depending on the value of your variable. Be sure to listen for the window **load** event if you plan on doing any DOM manipulation in your script.